# Why does the witch invoke "Zachiel" in "Jorinde and Joringel"?

Tags: angels, names, fairy-tales

In the Grimm Brothers' fairy tale "[Jorinde and Joringel](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Grimm%27s_Household_Tales,_Volume_1/Jorinda_and_Joringel)", the witch who has captured Jorinde and Joringel seems to cast a magic spell, as seen in the following excerpt:

> Joringel could neither speak nor move from the spot; the nightingale
> was gone. At last the woman came back, and said in a hollow voice,
> "Greet thee, Zachiel. If the moon shines on the cage, Zachiel, let him
> loose at once." Then Joringel was freed. He fell on his knees before
> the woman and begged that she would give him back his Jorinda, but she
> said that he should never have her again, and went away.

I'm wondering who Zachiel refers to, and why their name is invoked.  It seems like it could be a reference to the archangels [Zadkiel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zadkiel) or [Sachiel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sachiel), but I'm then confused why the witch (who is ostensibly evil in this story) is invoking the name of an angel in her magic ritual.  This also seems to appear in the [original German](https://books.google.com/books?id=y9tLAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA369#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Is there an explanation for this?